# React Native PIP Android: Display PIP view after app goes in background ( Android 13 )

Tags: react-native, android-13, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I want to start PIP mode when the application moves to the background state. In some devices AppState's change listener reflects before the application fully moves to the background in those cases I'm able to start PIP mode but in Android 13 devices, the "change" listener reflects when the application completely moves to the background at that time PIP mode view is not getting visible.

I'm calling PipHandler.enterPipMode() when app state changes to background but in android 13 devices when app state changes to background PipHandler.enterPipMode() didn't show PIP view.

Library used: https://github.com/adkaushik/react-native-pip-android

Open issue: https://github.com/adkaushik/react-native-pip-android/issues/7